# How to determine if its a Referential Integrity Violation exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I want a way to check in my catch {} clause if the exception is caused because of a Referential Integrity Violation, at the moment I am going by the method below;  is there a better/elegant/more-appropriate way to determine if its a referencial integrity exception?

```
public static bool IsReferencialIntegrityExcpetion(this Exception exception)
        {
            return exception is SqlException &&
                   exception.Message.Contains("The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint ");
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best you can do is catch the [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx) instead of the `Exception`. Then, instead of relying on the message, you could go by the [ErrorCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception.errorcode.aspx) (547). And, remember that you can stack exceptions and they will be handled in order (so place the more specific catches first. Your code would look like this:

```
try
{
}
catch(SqlException sqlEx)
{
    if(sqlEx.ErrorCode == 547)
        throw;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //General error logic
}
```

If you want a full list of the possible error codes, run `SELECT * FROM sysmessages` against the `MASTER` database

Comment: Ah the error code! yes this is exactly what I need, thank you indeed.

Comment: I had to double take, I read your name as Justin iPhony. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`SqlException` is thrown for *any* error that is returned from the database, regardless of what caused it (RI, constraint, type mismatch, size mismatch, etc.). You can't specifically *catch* only RI-based exceptions, but you can always examine the exception (ether as you are by looking at the message or, preferably, by looking at the `Errors` property) and `throw;` again (notice that it's just `throw;`, not `throw ex;`, as doing this preserves the stack trace) if you don't actually want to handle a particular exception.